# Check if textbox is empty

Tags: php

I have 2 textboxes called product1 and product2. I want to save to run different scripts when:
1. product1 and product2 are not empty;
2. only product1 is empty;
3. only product2 is empty;
4. product1 and product2 are not empty.

How can I define this in my php? For product1 (number 2) I am using:

```
if (isset($_POST['product1']) && !empty($_POST['product2'])) {
```

But this will also execute when product1 and product2 is empty.

Can someone help me to build a better check on this?

Here is what I have now. This is not executing the SQL:

```
if (isset($_POST['product1']) && isset($_POST['product2'])){
// SQL
} 
if (isset($_POST['product1']) && !empty($_POST['product2'])) {
// SQL
} 
if (!empty($_POST['product1']) && isset($_POST['product2'])) {
// SQL
} 
if (!empty($_POST['product1']) && !empty($_POST['product2'])) {
// SQL
}
```

The form I am using to post is:

```
<form name="reaction" method="post" action="./send1.php">
  <div class="col-md-12 xdisplay_inputx has-feedback">
    <input type="text" name="product1" id="product1" class="form-control has-feedback-left" aria-describedby="inputSuccess2Status4">
    <span class="fa fa-calendar-o form-control-feedback left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span id="inputSuccess2Status4" class="sr-only">(success)</span>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-12 xdisplay_inputx has-feedback">
    <input type="text" name="product2" id="product2" class="form-control has-feedback-left" aria-describedby="inputSuccess2Status4">
    <span class="fa fa-calendar-o form-control-feedback left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span id="inputSuccess2Status4" class="sr-only">(success)</span>
  </div>

<button class="btn btn-block btn-success" name="save"><i class="fa fa-check"></i>  Send</button>
</form>
```

Comment: No wait, your right. I need to check for: `1. both are empty`; `2. product1 is empty`; `3. product2 is empty` and `4. both are not empty`

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: Still not fixed

Comment: Still not fixed

Answer (score 0):

I created a simple form to represent this and it seems to work.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <table>
            <form action="result.php" method="post">
                <tr>
                    <td>Product 1:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="product1"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Product 2:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="product2"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="submit" value="SUBMIT"></td>
                </tr>
            </form>
            </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

result.php

```
<?php
    if ((!empty($_POST['product1'])) && (!empty($_POST['product2'])))
    {
    echo "Product 1 : SET<br>Product 2: SET";
    } 
    else if (!empty($_POST['product1']) && empty($_POST['product2'])) 
    {
    echo "Product 1 : SET<br>Product 2: NOT SET";
    } 
    else if (empty($_POST['product1']) && (!empty($_POST['product2']))) 
    {
    echo "Product 1 : NOT SET<br>Product 2: SET";
    } 
    else
    {
    echo "Product 1 : NOT SET<br>Product 2: NOT SET";
    }
?>
```

The first if statement is run when both textboxes contain something.
The next else if statement is run when product1 is set and product2 is empty.
The next else if statement is run when product1 is empty and product2 is set.
The last else statement is run when both are not set.

I did test this and it works, just change the echo to whatever SQL you need to run.

Comment: I tried to run the sql for `(!empty($_POST['product1']))&&(empty($_POST['product2'])` but it wont run the query

Comment: @John I rewrote my solution. Give it a look and try

Comment: I get a browser error: `This page isn’t working`. I turned on error reporting, but I still get `This page isn’t working`.

Comment: Make sure both files are inside the directory of the webserver. What webserver are you using? WAMP, XAMP?

Comment: Yes the files are on my webserver. I get the error in `result.php`. I am not using a webserver, its hosted (online).

Comment: I am trying to figure out now as to why, seen as it is working when I run it. What browser are you using? Not sure if that might make a difference. Or maybe try to put the php code with its tags withing html tags. Browser might have difficulty without them to display propperly. So I recomment in result.php, create all tags like in test.php. Then between <html> tags, put the php code.

Comment: I figured out what the problem was. But now I always get: `else
    {
    echo "Product 1 : NOT SET<br>Product 2: NOT SET";
    }`

Comment: Then I am not sure what is going on, tested on my side it is working. Hope someone else would have a better answer for you. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution:

```
$debug=true;
$executed='none';
if(isset($_POST['product1']) && !empty($_POST['product1']) && isset($_POST['product2']) && !empty($_POST['product2'])){
$executed='both';
//Both
}elseif(isset($_POST['product2']) && !empty($_POST['product2'])){
$executed='product2';
//Product2
}elseif(isset($_POST['product1']) && !empty($_POST['product1'])){
$executed='product2';
//Product1
}

if($debug){
  echo 'Executed '.$executed;
  print_r($_POST);
}
```

I've enabled debugging on it already, but you should turn that off once you know it's working.

Comment: When I try to execute the script with `product1` and `product2` empty, I get: `Executed noneArray`. When I execute the where `product1` is not empty I still get `Executed noneArray`

Comment: Also it is not printed as $_POST

Comment: Then your form is not sending the data to the script.

Comment: You should post the html that your using to show the form

Comment: Ok, html looks good. But for some reason, you're either not posting data OR there is something rewriting it. Do any other forms work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148141/discussion-between-greg-borbonus-and-john).